# Duplicate class error when importing Jersey client into Android project

Tags: java, android, jersey

I am trying the use Jersey in a Android project. This is my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.12'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:2.28'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

When I try and compile I get the following error:

```
Duplicate class javax.inject.Inject found in the following modules: jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:2.5.0), javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1) and javax.inject-2.3.0-b10.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.3.0-b10)
Duplicate class javax.inject.Named found in the following modules: jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:2.5.0), javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1) and javax.inject-2.3.0-b10.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.3.0-b10)
Duplicate class javax.inject.Provider found in the following modules: jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:2.5.0), javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1) and javax.inject-2.3.0-b10.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.3.0-b10)
Duplicate class javax.inject.Qualifier found in the following modules: jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:2.5.0), javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1) and javax.inject-2.3.0-b10.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.3.0-b10)
Duplicate class javax.inject.Scope found in the following modules: jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:2.5.0), javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1) and javax.inject-2.3.0-b10.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.3.0-b10)
Duplicate class javax.inject.Singleton found in the following modules: jakarta.inject-2.5.0.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:2.5.0), javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1) and javax.inject-2.3.0-b10.jar (org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.3.0-b10)
Duplicate class javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath found in modules jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar (jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:2.1.5) and javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1)
Duplicate class javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException found in modules jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.jar (jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:2.1.5) and javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar (javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1)
```

There are several more classes not found that I have not included in this post.

Comment: Same issue. Any luck with solving this?